# Prevent deleting a Core Data NSManagedObject

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a NSArrayController subclass which sets an instance variable of a newly inserted object and prevents the user to remove it if this variable is zero.

I'd like to do this inside an entity subclass. Setting the variable is possible in the awakeFromInsert method. Is there a way to prevent the deletion, a sort of:

```
if (self.testVariable == 0) return;   ?
```

I didn't find it, but maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this in your NSManagedObject:

```
- (BOOL)validateForDelete:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: Yes, your implementation must reflect your condition

Comment: You mean:(BOOL)validateForDelete:(NSError **)error {
return (self.testVariable != 0); }
??

Answer (score 1):

based on a few tests, i believe the `validateForDelete` will not work to prevent deletion as desired.

`validateForDelete` is used to perform added validation *prior* to delete. essentially, the method name is misleading. Just like for example, for

moreover, `prepareForDelete` is called prior and will delete any `Cascade` relationships and mark null any `Nullify` ones. hence, those have to be 'backed out.' or alter your data model to only permit `Deny` that will leave those relationships alone in prepareForDelete. which is applying a stiff backhand to your business model and logic.

further, a `Deny` relationship is 'denied' when the user saves the data -- which might be too late for the user to undo and rectify the situation.

i believe the best option is to unactive the Remove Button that is bound to the `canRemove` method in the Controller.

[Some solid opinions](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/232242-nsmanagedobject-validatefordelete-problem.html)
[Some possible solutions at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226085/nsmanagedobject-relationship-0/16226884#16226884)